# No way to leverage Tridion proximity logic in link resolving with DXA 2.0?

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-2.0, dynamic-linking

Tridion Dynamic Linking has built in proximity logic, that means that if the same component is on two pages, dynamic linking will link to the page which is 'nearest' the source page containing the link (using the algorithm described in the [docs](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web%20Cloud-v1/GUID-F9F52365-2ABE-4C1E-A50C-3D4CA4F84989)).

We are using DXA 2.0 and it seems that this proximity logic is not being applied when resolving links on a page returned from the Model Service. There doesn't seem to be any way to control which page links resolve to, which is a big problem for us as we have many subsites within a publication which reuse common content items, within their own subsite context page - the dynamic link within a subsite should thus always be to a page within that subsite.

Having checked the [code](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/issues/104), it seems that the page context is never taken into account when resolving links in DXA, which seems like a big omission. Am I missing something, or is there really no way to leverage proximity logic when resolving links in DXA 2.0?

Has anyone else encountered and/or worked around this issue?

Comment: Also created an idea for this: https://community.sdl.com/ideas/sdl-tridion-dx-ideas/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/i/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/have-dxa-use-standard-tridion-link-resolving-proximity-logic

Comment: And 2 Pull Requests with the code fix: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-model-service/pull/5, https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/pull/114